# When I write sucessives numbers in squares delimeters inside itemize environment, do not compile

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, itemize

When I write sucessives numbers in squares delimeters inside itemize environment, do not compile.

This is my code.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,draft]{beamer}



\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[figurename=Fig]{caption}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\frame{\frametitle{Importancia del estudio de las Bandas de Energia} 

Diferentes investigacion que obtienen las bandas de energia, para el estudio de propiedades fisicas.
\begin{itemize}
\item Resitencia a la corrosion, y puntos altos de fusión para NaCl y CsCl.\par\medskip
[1]
\item  Estructurales, mecanicas, electronicas y opticas para FCC en TiN, VN, CrN, NbN, W2N,\par\medskip
 [2]
\item Propiedades Unicas del compuesto CrN son analizadas a partir de las bandas de Energia.\par\medskip
 [5],[6],[7]
\end{itemize}•

}

\frame{\frametitle{Bibliografia}
[1] Tanmoy Das, Sudipta Deb, Abhijit Mookerjee, Physica B 367 (2005) 6–18.
[2] F. L´evy, P. Hones, P.E. Schmid, R. Sanjin´es, M. Diserens, C. Wiemer, Surf. Coat. Technol. 120–121 (1999),284–290.
[5] A. Dasgupta, P.A. Premkumar, F. Lawrence, L. Houben, P. Kuppusami, M. Luysberg, K.S. Nagaraja,V.S. Raghunathan, Surf. Coat. Technol. 201 (2006) 1401–1408.
[6] P. Cai, W. Zhang, L. Chen, Y. Qian, J. Alloys Compounds 414 (2006) 221–223.
[7] K. Inumaru, H. Okamoto, S. Yamanaka, J. Crystal Growth 237–239 (2002) 2050–2054.

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The example compiles perfectly; are you sure you don't have something like ``\\ [1]``? If you have, then use ``\\\relax [1]``

Comment: I have no problems compiling this, but what is the perpose of using [1] etc? Do you want to make a citation to some journal/book?

Comment: By the way, you are missing many many accents.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, it is a citation and is generating problems to compile, I have add the bibliography to the post. Maybe I shoul citate in some especial way?

Comment: @JuanMuñoz: Yes, of course, using the `\cite` command and a `.bib` file in conjunction with `bibtex`, or (better) `biber`

Comment: How is exactly the procces @ChristianHupfer?

Comment: See [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast) (look for the PDF).  Or, if you use TeX Live, the following command should work to get the same document: `texdoc ttb`.  There's also this one, which is written in [Spanish](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/spanish/guia-bibtex) (which means I can't really comment on how useful it is).

Comment: @JuanMuñoz: See the link provided by jon... it's too much to explain in comments here